# Cordova-android platform and Google Play's target API level 33 update

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-api-levels, cordova-android

I am developing a Sencha ExtJS application which have Android app version. I faced the problem to have  to support Google Play target API level 33. Now the Cordova CLI is v10, Cordova-android platform is version 9, and the targetSdkVersion is 31. Can i only change targetSdkVersion, or have to update Cordova, Cordova-android platform to v11 or v12? In that case wouldn't I have to change the version of Cordova or Node.js as well?
I would be grateful if someone could share what the versions of the whole stack are - node.js, cordova, cordova-android, gradle, etc.
Тhanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [cordova official documentations](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/index.html) and [recent blog post](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2023/05/22/cordova-android-12.0.0.html) to target Android API-Level 33 cordova-android version 12 is required and Node minimum version is 16.13.0.

Complete minimim requirements to target Android API-Level 33 are:

- cordova: 12.0.0
- cordova-android: 12.0.x
- Nodejs: 16.13.0
- Build Tools: ^33.0.2
- Kotlin: 1.7.21
- Gradle: 7.6
- Android Gradle Plugin: 7.4.2
- AndroidX Compat Library: 1.6.1
- AndroidX WebKit Library: 1.6.0
- AndroidX Core SplashScreen: 1.0.0
- Google Services Gradle Plugin: 4.3.15

Comment: Note: i'm testing upgrading my app with 33 targetSdkVersion (cordova 11, cordova-android 11) and the build still seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Cordova's official requirement for the **targetSdkVersion: 33** (Android API-Level) is cordova-android Version: 12.0.x,

I was able to upgrade the **targetSdkVersion** and **compileSdkVersion** from 31 to 33 without any issues. My Cordova CLI is v10.1 and the Cordova-android platform is version 9.1.0.

I tested my application and it works really well. I pushed the update to the Play Store as well.

Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The situation is exactly the same to me, Cordova CLI is v10, and the cordova-android is 9.1.0, the app builds correctly. Fingers crossed that it works properly and passes this Google Play check for target API level 33

Comment: I am updating Android Studio for everything for API Level 33.  I am running `Cordova CLI 11.1.0` and `cordova-android 11.0` - hoping just changing the `config.xml` `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` from current 32 to new 33 without any issue.  Above responses are encouraging.  I will report back with results.  Not ready for the mental gynmastics required to upgrade to `Cordova 12.0`

Comment: In my Cordova app, both `compile` and `target` were set to 32, with `'minimum` set to 22.  I changed the `targetSdkVersion` to 33 and recompiled the app.  During the compile I get a warning from the Cordova CLI:  `The "android-compileSdkVersion" (32) should be greater than or equal to the "android-targetSdkVersion" (33).`  That being said, the app compiled fine and launched without issue.  So far, all is good.