# IONIC v3 with API 33 Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-api-33

In my company they left me an app made in ionic v3, and Google asks to use version 33 of the Android API, for different reasons, the company cannot afford to update from version 3 of ionic to 5, is it possible to use the Android version 33 with IONIC v3?

know if in ionic v3 it is possible to use android api 33 without updating to v5 or higher of ionic

Comment: you need to update you cordova-android version to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic v3 uses Cordova for generating native app.
So the question is :
Can Cordova Android target API 33 ?
[Cordova-android platform and Google Play's target API level 33 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76938718/cordova-android-platform-and-google-plays-target-api-level-33-update)

Answer (score 0):

It *may* be possible, but it won't be supported by Ionic. According to [this Ionic page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/support#native-bridges) Ionic 3 is only supported against Cordova 8, but you need Cordova 12 to have API 33 support. That's not to say Ionic 3 won't work with Cordova 12, but it won't be supported.